# Error when trying to download mysql in a trial django project

Tags: python, mysql, pip

when I enter this line `pip3 install mysqlclient` it gives me this error :

> **ERROR:** Command errored out with exit status 1:

this happened after I tried using `pip install mysqlclient`

Answer (score 0):

You have to install some Prerequisites
 https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python#prerequisites

Did you already install those?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `pip` or `pip3` in Windows operating system ;

- `PYTHONPATH` system variable should be added to environment variables for the path of
  `python.exe` file such as
  `C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\`
- `PATH` system variable should be edited by adding new paths such as
  `C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\` and 
  `C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\`

Then, both of the variables might be checked whether they're set from command line by

`C:\Users\pc>echo %PYTHONPATH%` and `C:\Users\pc>echo %PATH%`

Comment: I have done this and I still get the same error message